# Lan printing issue HP 8600 pro

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

I'm having random issues with lan printing.

#### Network composition:

- 2 PCs (Windows 8) are connected by Ethernet
- 2 Macs (10.9 & 10.10) are connected by Wi-Fi
- 1 PC (Windows 8) is connected by Wi-Fi
- 1 HP 8600 pro printer connected by Wi-Fi

All are configured with statics IP outside of the range of the DHCP configuration.

#### Issue

Sometimes, and without any notable cause, the two Ethernet PCs are unable to print, no matter how many time I clean the printing queue, reboot the PC or/and the printer while *all* the wireless devices are able to print. (note: it also disable the scanning function).

I don't know if it's useful but during this time I can access shared folder of any computer in the local network.

And then after a few minutes/hours, it goes back to normal.

What can I do to fix this? Where should I dig?

(Note: I'd like to avoid a call to both ISP or HP support team since both will tell me that it's the other fault...)

Comment: Need some clarification...You said "*without any notable cause, the two Ethernet PCs are enable to print*". Did you mean **unable** to print? Also, why would you have to call the ISP? Isn't this a LAN? Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: @CharlieRB you're right, I meant unable to print. And the router is provided by my ISP and is quite old (8yo)

Comment: In that case, you may want to clarify the details about the router in the question. It (the router) is a big part of the ability to print over the network. Have you attempted resetting/rebooting the router? Have you verifed you are using the most up to date drivers for the printer? I would uninstall the printers and reinstall. Sometimes the drivers can get corrupted and cause issues.

Comment: When this happens, are you able to surf the Internet from the PCs in question? What happens if you try to ping the printer's IP address?

Comment: Are you accessing the printer by IP or name? Macs doing SMB on Win networks can often force a re-election of master browser, & win, even if they should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got bored and buy a switch and 3 Ethernet wires, now I'm able to print & scan faster than ever without any disturbance. Long life to the wire.